# Find the angle between a line and a plane

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to solve the following:

A clock rests on a stand so that it’s face makes an angle of $68^0$ with the horizontal. Find the angle made with the horizontal by the minute hand at (a) 08.10, (b) 07.25.

I assume the hour hands are irrelevant. I am trying to visualise the situation (see diagram) and I realise 10 past the hour makes an angle of $54^0$ with the horizontal [image]but can proceed no further.

Comment: Is 08.10, 8 minutes and 10 seconds?

Comment: No. 10 minutes past 8.

Comment: Ok, then just take a look at the last line in my solution and you will be able to workout the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this using trigonometry if you construct three right triangles in a useful way.

The first right triangle, $\triangle ABD,$ lies in the plane of the clock face,
where the hypotenuse, $AB,$ is the minute hand, and the leg $AD$ lies along the line from the center of the face to the number $3$ at the side of the dial.
Therefore $AD$ is parallel to the horizontal plane.
For simplicity you can choose your unit of length so that $AB=1.$

At $10$ minutes past the hour the minute hand has traveled $\frac{10}{60} = \frac16$ of the way around the dial. Figure that out in degrees (it's not $54$ and it's not $90-54=36$ either). Then subtract this from $90$ degrees, which was the initial angle between the minute hand and $AD.$
That's angle $\theta = \angle BAD.$

Then you can use the usual trig definitions to find that $BD = \sin\theta.$

Next let $\pi_A$ be a plane through $A$ parallel to the horizontal plane and let 
$C$ be the foot of the perpendicular from $B$ to the plane $\pi_A$.
Note that $D$ also lies in this same plane.
Then $\triangle BCD$ is a right triangle with a right angle at $C.$
You can use trig again to find the length $BC.$

Now observe that $\triangle ABC$ is a right triangle with right angle at $C.$
Moreover, this triangle is in a plane perpendicular to the horizontal plane and $AB$ is the minute hand, so $\angle BAC$ is the angle that the minute hand makes with the horizontal plane. You should already know $AB$ and $BC.$
Use these to find $\angle BAC.$

A diagram would help. I have not drawn one, partly to save my own time and partly so that you may have the benefit of doing it yourself. It's a good exercise. (Your diagram already shows $\triangle ABC$ and the plane $\pi_A$ so you just need to add a couple more lines and label the point $D$.
You actually have drawn the mirror image of what the problem describes, but the angles will be the same.)

Comment: I think BD = sin θ but thanks for a very clear explanation.

Comment: Thanks for catching the error. I guess that means the rest of the explanation was clear enough!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try using $ x(t) = A\cos(\omega t + \phi) $. 
You can imagine that the angle with the instantenious angle is $ \phi(t) = \theta(t)+\phi_0 $ where $ \theta(t) = -\omega t $ ($\omega$ angular frequency, $t$ time, negative sign for clockwise movement) and $ \phi_0 = 68 $. The angular frequency can be expressed as $ \omega = \frac{360}{T} $ where $ T $ is the period and for a clock it is 60 minutes. For a time $ t = 8.1 $ min you get:
$$ \phi(t) = -\frac{360\cdot8.1}{60} + 68 = 19.4 $$
So for any time $ t $ expressed in minutes the formula for the angle is:
$$ \phi(t) =  -\frac{360\cdot t}{60} + 68$$
If the time in your question is given as time in hours and minutes on a clock just find the time in minutes (from 0 to 60 minutes) which corresponds to the given time.

Comment: The equations set up here are for a completely different problem than the one asked in the question.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Use the right triangles in the diagram to evaluate,

$$ BC = BD\> \sin 68 = AB \>\sin 54 \>\sin 68$$

Thus,

$$\sin \beta = \frac {BC}{AB} = \sin 54 \>\sin 68 $$